# Excel not updating after macro

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel workbook doesn't update after running a macro until a double click with the left mouse button despite having

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

At the end of the code. I tried selecting and activating a cell to no avail

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("A6").Select
Range("A6").Activate
```

The macro is quite intensive in memory for about 40 seconds and then it is complete. I don't want to post the whole macro as some of it is proprietary. However it's a standard macro using built in Excel functions.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't update"? Calculate? Screan update? What does your code do? This is not enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: **A problem exists in that part of the code that you have chosen not to post.**

Comment: Ok, just to be clear: the problem you mentioned is not an excel error. It is your macro. It does something wrong. We can't help you unless you post your code, or the part that produces the error.

Comment: The operations will complete without error, but the the workbook screen does not update to show the changes until an event such as a mouse double click. Everything that I disabled during the code is re-enabled in the final steps before the end sub.

Comment: The problem also only exits when the file size for importing and manipulation is large. There are no problems with a 1mb csv file but a 3.6mb csv file causes the issues which is why I don't think its a code problem. Is there any way that I can force Excel to update the screen once the userform has closed?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a Form Control button on a sheet with a macro assigned to it? If so I've been having issues with the sheets not being properly activated and your workaround of selecting a different sheet and then back again was the same workaround I initially employed.

If that is the case, try replacing the Button (Form control) with a Command Button (ActiveX control) and add the sub below to the correct sheet.

```
'You can create this by right clicking the button after placing it and click 'View Code'
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'Or Private Sub WhatEverYourButtonIsCalled_Click()
    Call TheMacroYouWantToUse
End Sub
```

I understand this might be more comment worthy than answer worthy but I'm still 8 reputation points shy of being able to comment freely so I will apologize in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if the workbook is in manual calculation mode and then try and force the worksheet to recalculate at the end of the macro.

```
Worksheet(1).Calculate
```

Comment: This does seem to update some of the cells to display but unfortunately not all of them. The workbook functions normally again if I switch to another Sheet and then Back again. All of the cell values exist but excel seems to have a graphical glitch that needs the worksheet reloading. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried your code on another computer? Maybe it is just you computer that gets fried.

Comment: @kestertonj What about adding a workbook refresh instead `Workbooks(1).RefreshAll`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't give the desired effect either. I have just tried the macro on another version of Excel (Excel 2010) on another computer and it runs without any problems at all. Therefore the problem is either, Office 365 or my computer graphics. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Since this question is not about programming, but a simple hardware error, please consider deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment due to not having enough posts, I have to post this as an answer: SilentRevolution's solution is correct, I was having this issue as well and after reading his answer realized it was only in workbooks where I had run a form control that I encountered it.

I only think it's important to post this because earlier answers dismissed this as even being a programming issue, but it is an Office 365 Excel VBA problem not a hardware problem.

It was not a problem in earlier versions of Excel, and will not be able to be duplicated in them.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had a similar problem producing Maths worksheets using VBA Excel 2016.

I used interconnected subroutines each using a home made `rndb()` function which itself uses the `rnd()` function. The first time after loading pressing the "new Q's type 1" button would seem to not update the sheet if the last use was "new Q's type 1", but would for other types and for type 1's on subsequent attempts.

It turned out it was generating new, but identical, questions (including a 6 digit random sheet reference number) the first time it was run due to `rnd()` ... cured by including "randomize" in amongst the plethora of, now known to be redundant, `ScreenUpdating = True` statements.